# fa fa spinner not displaying in the browser

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-5, font-awesome

I have a command like this in my index.html.erb

```
<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" style="font-size:24px"></i>
```

When i open the html in chrome the spinner is not displaying. I've tried with safari too. Any one know whats the problem

In my form submission also it is not working. I've my submit as follows

```
 <%= f.button  button_label, class: "btn btn-success ",id: "submit", data: {disable_with: "<i class: 'fa fa-spinner fa-spin' ></i> Saving..."} %>
```

I'm using rails 5.1.6 and ruby 2.5.1p57

Comment: what version of font-awesome do you use?

Comment: because in version 5 it works perfect:https://jsfiddle.net/se7j6k9p/

Comment: do you include fontawesome in your project?

Comment: @לבנימלכה Working fine. I forgot include font-awesome itself

Comment: @mast3rd3mon No. Just now included that working fine

Comment: Happy to help you can learn here:https://fontawesome.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to include the css file for the font awesome.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```